# Special character (&) causing syntax error in jQuery method / selector?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm getting a "Syntax error, unrecognized expression" when running the following jQuery:

```js
$element = $('.header__navigation .menu-item > .megamenu__item__link:focus');
var href = $element.attr('href');   // Example: #one-&-two

$('#mega-menu').find(href).toggleClass('active'); // it breaks here
```

What options do I have where the href value would be `#one-&-two` and I'm trying to toggle the class on an element within a div#mega-menu with `id="#one-&-two"` ?

I've tried escaping the '&' character in the "href" variable like below:

```
$('#mega-menu').find(href.replace('/&/g','&amp;')).toggleClass('active');
```

Comment: In the element, replace the `&` with `&amp;` and try again